# Programmatically trigger ReportViewer Toolbar controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, reportviewer, toolbar

Does anyone know a way of how to trigger the controls inside a ReportViewer(VS2005) Toolbar?
I'm specifically interested in creating two buttons which I can click to go forward and backwards in the displayed report. I know that the default toolbar gives me this functionality, but the size of the forward and backwards buttons are too small for a touchscreen. This is why I thought about adding two custom buttons, that could be able to trigger the same events that the toolbar's forward and backwards buttons invoke. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example in VB.NET how to edit the toolbar of the ReportViewer component, like adding images to dropdown items or anything you like:

```
Private Sub AddImgRVToolBar()
    Dim ts As ToolStrip = Me.FindToolStrip(Of ToolStrip)(Me.ReportViewer1)

            If ts IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim exportButton As ToolStripDropDownButton = TryCast(ts.Items("export"), ToolStripDropDownButton)

                If exportButton IsNot Nothing Then
                    AddHandler exportButton.DropDownOpened, AddressOf OnExportOpened
                End If
            End If
End Sub

    Private Sub OnExportOpened(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            If TypeOf sender Is ToolStripDropDownButton Then
                Dim button As ToolStripDropDownButton = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripDropDownButton)

                For Each item As ToolStripItem In button.DropDownItems
                    Dim extension As RenderingExtension = DirectCast(item.Tag, RenderingExtension)

                    If extension IsNot Nothing Then
                        Select Case extension.Name
                            Case "Excel"
                                item.Image = My.Resources.page_white_excel_16x16
                            Case "PDF"
                                item.Image = My.Resources.page_white_acrobat_16x16
                            Case "WORD"
                                item.Image = My.Resources.page_white_word_16x16
                                item.Text = "Word"
                        End Select
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Function FindToolStrip(Of T As System.Windows.Forms.Control)(ByVal control As Control) As T
            If control Is Nothing Then
                Return Nothing
            ElseIf TypeOf control Is T Then
                Return DirectCast(control, T)
            Else
                Dim result As T = Nothing

                For Each embedded As Control In control.Controls
                    If result Is Nothing Then
                        result = FindToolStrip(Of T)(embedded)
                    End If
                Next

                Return result
            End If
        End Function
```

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for I forgot to mention that I'm a C# developer, and a VB.NET developer. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: So you know both languages, C# and VB.NET? But it doesn't matter, you can understand the point from this example, just add this: `exportButton.PerformClick()` to trigger a button in toolbar.